# How can I delete duplicate records if one of the records has a NULL field?

Tags: sql-server-2012, coldfusion

This is the STUDENTS table:

```
UID     NAME    SPECIALTY

123456  John    Writing
123456  John    NULL
234567  Jane    Acting
234567  Jane    NULL
345678  Bob     Writing
345678  Bob     NULL
```

I want to run a query where it will delete all records with a duplicate UID and a NULL Specialty. I am using ColdFusion, MSQL 2012.

Thank you.

Comment: What if all records for a UID have NULL SPWCIALTY? Do all get deleted, all but one, or none? ie Bob has 2 NULLs

Comment: Oops. `SPECIALTY`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you do something like:

```
delete
  from students s1
 where specialty is null
   and exists(select 1
                from students s2
               where specialty is not null
                 and s2.uid = s1.uid);
```

This is a correlated sub-query in Oracle.  Not sure about your environment.

Comment: The question is tagged sql-server.  However this answer works in that system.

Comment: Thanks, I suspected it would work for sql server, but wasn't sure.

Comment: I am using ColdFusion builder to run these commands. If I do this:
    SELECT *  
    FROM dbo.students s1
    WHERE specialty is null
    AND EXISTS(
     SELECT *
     FROM dbo.students s2
     WHERE specialty is not null
     AND s2.uid = s1.uid
     )

I can see the records I want to delete. However, If I do this:

    DELETE
    FROM dbo.students s1
    WHERE specialty is null
    AND EXISTS(
     SELECT 1
     FROM dbo.students s2
     WHERE specialty is not null
     AND s2.uid = s1.uid
     )
I get an error that says "Incorrect syntax near s1"

Comment: I'm sorry I can't do the format properly for the code.

Comment: For future references, when making comments, if you surround anything, `code for example`, with backticks, it will sort of look like code because of the `grey background`.

Comment: The reason your `DELETE` doesn't is because you can't alias the `FROM` table in a `DELETE`. Change it to `DELETE FROM dbo.students WHERE ..... AND s2.uid = dbo.students.uid )`.

Comment: @JimB I was able to use your code to update a different column (specialty_id) with 777 and that took. From there, I was able to delete everything with 777 as their special ID. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @Shawn Thanks for this. I'm sure I'll encounter this issue again and I will have use of your new code.

Comment: @JimB This query won't delete duplicates,if all records of an UID have NULL speciality.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following query in MS-SQL server,

```
DELETE FROM
    students 
WHERE
    specialty IS NULL 
    AND UID IN (
        SELECT 
            UID 
        FROM 
            students 
        GROUP BY 
            UID 
        HAVING 
            COUNT(*) > 1
    )
```

Comment: Danger here if a student has 2 records with a null specialty (and no records with a specialty) - both of the records will be deleted.

Comment: That is a possible interpretation of the requirement as stated in the question.

Comment: @JimB That is the requirement of the user   "*delete all records with a duplicate UID and a NULL Specialty*".

Comment: @JimB If you are considering 2 records with a NULL specialty means, even your answer won't delete duplicate records, if all records of an UID have NULL specialty.